# React Router Link params. Unexpected character '`'. in uglify and eslint

Tags: reactjs, react-router, eslint, gulp-uglify

I am getting unexpected character '`' when using gulp uglify & eslint both.

```
<td><Link to={`/user/${u.userId}`}>{u.UserName}</Link></td>
```

In gulp file

```
Gulp.task('js', function(){
    Browserify(GulpConfig.paths.mainJs, { debug: (production() ? false : true)})
        .transform(Reactify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(Source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(production(Buffer()))
        .pipe(production(Uglify().on('error', gulpUtil.log)))
        .pipe(Gulp.dest(GulpConfig.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
        .pipe(Connect.reload());
});
```

How to handle it?

Comment: i guess you should do it like tat: <td><Link to={"/user/${u.userId}"}>{u.UserName}</Link></td>

Comment: @ius No. Backticks are here for ES6 string concatenation.

Comment: @Aperçu It's not string concatenation, it's a template string.

Comment: if you want to concatenate should be something like that. <td><Link to={"/user/" + u.userId}>{u.UserName}</Link></td> why do you need the $?

Comment: @limelights When someone doesn't know an es6 feature, it's better to explain it in es5 words I think ;)

Comment: Yes, agree but it's not a concatenation that's happening. It is by all means a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of ES6 template strings require you to transpile your code through a tool like [Babel](http://babeljs.io), which you're not doing currently.

However since you're using `reactify` you can add the option `{"es6": true}` in order to take part in some of the ES6 features such as arrow function or template strings.

```
.transform(Reactify, {es6: true})
```

The [entire feature set](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify#es6-transformation) that reactify currently supports are arrow functions, rest params, templates, object short notation and classes.

If you plan on doing React and ES6 for the long haul I certainly recommend using [Babel](http://babeljs.io) as your one-stop-shop instead of doing all that jazz with browserify, reactify, both which are awesome tools and has helped me tremendously in the past.